# javascript function using an if variable

Tags: javascript

If `success: function(result)` is false than `alert()` but if it's true i want to redirect. Can anyone help me with this question.

```
 function log_me_in_now() {

    var eml = $('#email').val();
    var pwd = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev/ajax/shopper_login.php',
        data: { 'email': eml, 'password': pwd },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        failure: function(results) {
            alert('99 problems...\n' + results);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            //window.location = "http://dev/test/logged_in"
        }
    });
}
```

ajax:

```
include_once('../includes/settings.php');

if (isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] != '' && isset($_GET['password']) && $_GET['password'] != '') {

    // todo: change their connection string to become their Oracle user.
    $shopper = new Shopper($_GET['email']);
    $token = $shopper->login($_GET['password']);

    if (isset($token) && $token != '') {
        echo json_encode($token);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's true you want to alert... and if it's true you want to redirect? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: So use an if statement???

Comment: if it's true redirect... not alert.

Comment: not good with my javascript if statements.

Comment: You have a problem with your response or redirect code ?

Comment: it's always redirecting when you hit login... so it's not verifying anything anymore.

Comment: _not good with my javascript if statements._ You have no business programming with this attitude.

Comment: The `success` and `failure` keys refer to the Ajax call itself. What does `result` look like?

Comment: What kind of data are you getting back from your ajax call?  Right now, it's just going to redirect if the ajax call is successful, it doesn't actually do any validation here.

Comment: updated with ajax call.

Comment: maybe you need something like:  if(result=="true"){//redirect}else{alert("bad")};  Depending on what is being returned in result.

Comment: That sounds right @HowardRenollet, how do i incorporate that into my code.

Comment: @cook - I've posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            success: function(result) {
                if (result == "true") {
                    window.location = "http://dev/test/logged_in"                    
                }
                else{
                    alert("Login Failed -- Please try again.");                    
                };
            }
```

This is dependent upon what is actually being returned by your ajax call.  Theoretically, it should just return "true" or "false" if the login is correct.  If this is truly what is returned by the call, then the code above will work for you.

Comment: How do I push the php variables into the GET when they land on the logged_in page?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little rusty on my php, I'm primarily a C# dev anymore.  Couldn't you pass them through the query string?  What exactly are you trying to pass to the subsequent page?  A unique token perhaps?  You could try something like this to pass the token through the query string:  *" http : // dev / test / logged_in "  + results.token*

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

function log_me_in_now() {

```
var eml = $('#email').val();
var pwd = $('#password').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dev/ajax/shopper_login.php',
    data: { 'email': eml, 'password': pwd },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    failure: function(results) {
        alert('99 problems...\n' + results);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        window.location.assign("http://dev/test/logged_in");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: The problem is if i try to redirect it's redirecting even if the credentials are filled in.

Comment: It means you ajax redirect not work good ? if sucess false still redirecting ?

Answer (score 0):

Check it ! 
your submit is required preventdefault false for default browser !

```
$("#inputID" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
var eml = $('#email').val();
var pwd = $('#password').val();

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://dev/ajax/shopper_login.php',
      data: { 'email': eml, 'password': pwd },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      failure: function(results) {
        alert('99 problems...\n' + results);
      },
      success: function(result) {
        window.location.assign("http://dev/test/logged_in");
      }
    });
});
```